# livy-server build failing on Windows while running mvn -e clean install -DskipTests command in cmd prompt?

Tags: apache-spark, livy, maven-install

I'm executing cmd: mvn -e clean install -DskipTests on windows to set up apache livy which is giving livy-server build failure. The following are the error logs:

```
[INFO] Livy Project Parent POM ............................ SUCCESS [  3.803 s]
[INFO] livy-api ........................................... SUCCESS [  9.125 s]
[INFO] livy-client-common ................................. SUCCESS [  5.708 s]
[INFO] livy-test-lib ...................................... SUCCESS [  7.374 s]
[INFO] livy-rsc ........................................... SUCCESS [  9.376 s]
[INFO] multi-scala-project-root ........................... SUCCESS [  0.406 s]
[INFO] livy-core-parent ................................... SUCCESS [  0.640 s]
[INFO] livy-core_2.11 ..................................... SUCCESS [22:01 min]
[INFO] livy-repl-parent ................................... SUCCESS [  3.447 s]
[INFO] livy-repl_2.11 ..................................... SUCCESS [ 22.895 s]
[INFO] livy-server ........................................ FAILURE [  0.203 s]
[INFO] livy-assembly ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-client-http ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-scala-api-parent .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-scala-api_2.11 ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-integration-test .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-coverage-report ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-examples ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] livy-python-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-03T18:12:32+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The logs show that an ant build exception has occurred:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project livy-server: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project livy-server: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Windows\System32\incubator-livy\server\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

Can anyone help resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Livy doesn't support windows yet. If you read your log message carefully it mentions bash.

When I did run the command 'mvn clean package -DskipTsets', I got the below error:

*[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireOS failed with message:
OS Arch: amd64 Family: dos Name: windows 10 Version: 10.0 is not allowed by Family=unix*

Also, if you download the bin from apache livy website, it only contains the shell script so you need to try alternatives.